# syntax error при восстановлении из дампа

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, dump

Есть дамп базы MySQL - `dump.sql`, который мне отдали сторонние разработчики. Кодировка - cp1251.

Нужно ее мигрировать на postgresql.

Что делаю:

1) восстанавливаю дамп в базу(разработчики по-своему ее выгружают, поэтому решил сделать дамп самостоятельно)

2) делаю свой дамп

```
mysqldump --compatible=postgresql -u root catalog > dump.sql
```

3) конвертирую дамп для postgresql (знаю, что это всего лишь текстовый файл, но тем не менее просто восстановить из sql не получалось)
Делаю это утилитой https://github.com/lanyrd/mysql-postgresql-converter

`python db_converter.py dump.sql pg_dump`

4) Пытаюсь восстановить `psql pg_database < pg_dump`

На данный момент выходит такая ошибка

```
START TRANSACTION
SET
SET
SET CONSTRAINTS
invalid command \"?????????
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "0"
LINE 5:     "price" float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
                                            ^
```

Подскажите в чем проблема? как исправлять такие ошибки?